# How to include measurement bias correction in GEKKO for model predictive control MPC?

Tags: gekko

I need to include the bias correction term in my MPC calculation. This is the difference between model predictions and measurements at each time instant. How to specify in GEKKO?

Comment: Hi Hari: can you please provide a complete and replicable example of what you're trying to do, so people can more accurately provide you with assistance?

Answer (score 1):

GEKKO has a tuning parameter called *BIAS* that should give you what you want. To quote from the [GEKKO documentation on *BIAS*](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tuning_params.html#bias):

> *BIAS* is additive factor that incorporates the difference between the current measured value and the initial condition of the controller. *FSTATUS* determines how much of the raw measurement is used to update the value of *MEAS*. A feedback status of 0 indicates that the measurement should not be used and the *BIAS* value is kept at the initial value of 0. A feedback status of 1 uses all of the measurement in updating *MEAS*. A feedback status in between 0 and 1 updates *MEAS* with a fractional contribution from LSTVAL and the new measurement. The value of BIAS is updated from MEAS and the unbiased model prediction (*Model_u*).
>
> *BIAS* = *MEAS* − *Model_u*
>
> The *BIAS* is added to each point in the horizon and the controller objective function drives the biased model (*Model_b*) to the requested set point range.
>
> *Model_b* = *Model_u* + *BIAS*
>
> The value of *BIAS* can also be set to an external value by setting the option BIAS option directly and setting *FSTATUS* to 0 (OFF).

So if you want to automatically align your model predictions with your measured values, set the feedback status to 1 for each CV in your model (`model_name.variable_name.FSTATUS = 1`).

You can also compute the bias correction term yourself each time you have a new measurement by subtracting the predicted value from the prior MPC cycle at the appropriate time step from the corresponding new measurement.